# How can I get a unique Id of each visitor? php

Tags: javascript, php, html

In php

I've created for each user a unique URL that if someone opens that URL points to be added to account user.

My problem here is that anyone can do it only once.

How can I get a unique Id of each visitor that does not duplicate?

How can I get information hardware PC or Mobile visitor?

Comment: Please read here: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Look to [$_SERVER](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php), particularly `HTTP_USER_AGENT` and `REMOTE_ADDR`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **uniqid()** function to have a uniq id and store the value on a cookie.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need another database that will store if the user has clicked on the link.
Once the link is clicked, You will need to check if the link has been clicked previously (the way you store this data is up to you).

If Yes: Alert the user.

If No:
You will then need to write to a database signifying that the link has been pressed, and the next time the link is clicked, you should get an alert.

As for detecting if Mobile or PC, take a look at this library:
http://mobiledetect.net/

Comment: another database?

Comment: You could have another database, or you could write it to your existing user database if you only have 1 link per person.

Comment: I know ,But what my users got to save that can never change it?

Answer (score 0):

The servers PHP session that is generated for each visiter per visit is unique as well.